# Did Hamas bake a baby to death in an oven?

Tags: israel, israel-hamas-war, hamas

A new report has emerged of [Hamas baking a baby in an oven.](https://gellerreport.com/2023/10/islamic-atrocities-baby-was-found-in-an-oven-baked-to-death-by-hamas-terrorists.html) [NSFL images at link] ([Video](https://youtu.be/nKNPz51lTig?t=1987) of the Eli Beer speech referenced in the Tweet embedded in that previous article.) This has also, of course, [been immediately denied.](https://twitter.com/GwansunRyu/status/1718747066594431468)

Is it true? Has this been confirmed by a journalist, news source, or an official of the Israeli government?

Comment: FWTW, there's an [interview with him](https://youtu.be/ssiiZW9e6xw?t=101) in which he suggests *multiple* children were decaptitated at the same location: "we were trying to figure out which head belongs to which child". I haven't really followed the decapitated children saga, but last I recall, only one decapitated baby was confirmed seen by Vach. Anyhow, Beer's claims do raise an eyebrow. They could be true, but one could make several more Qs here just from that one interview with him.

Comment: I watched the whole TBN segment now, but he doesn't say/repeat in there the story about the baby in oven.

Comment: @Fizz the tweet is specific about when and where Eli said this, at the RJC event

Comment: @Fizz you can see it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKNPz51lTig&ab_channel=NTD at 33:19.

Comment: @SIMEL: thanks. At least we know he said it.

Comment: [Testimony of medic Asher Moskowitz](https://twitter.com/BenjaminSales/status/1719531771736252566), who helped receive the baby in question at at Camp Shura, talking about how the baby had the sign of a heating element having been applied directly. And how the medics who brought the baby in said that it appeared that after the parents were gruesomely murdered, apparently the baby had been placed alive in the kitchen oven, and then oven had been turned on with the baby in it (adding as comment as I dont have rep on this site to answer).

Comment: [Corresponding article](https://www.jta.org/2023/10/31/israel/an-israeli-first-responder-recalls-tending-to-the-body-of-a-baby-burnt-in-an-oven) from the Jewish Telegraphic agency giving more details as well.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to write an answer here, but Haaretz has reported that this report is false. https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-04/ty-article-magazine/.premium/hamas-committed-documented-atrocities-but-a-few-false-stories-feed-the-deniers/0000018c-34f3-da74-afce-b5fbe24f0000

Answer (score 10):

This has not been confirmed by a reputable source. According to [FakeReporter on Twitter](https://twitter.com/FakeReporter/status/1718908536749449689) (Hebrew):

1. Eli Beer's speech is currently the only source, it was first quoted by Dovid Efune. Eli Beer is the founder of United Hatzalah, a medical first responder organization in Israel, and he is privy to a lot of information that is not yet public.
2. Eli Beer did not respond to a request for comment (yet).
3. [Israeli journalist Ishai Cohen reports](https://twitter.com/ishaycoen/status/1718888165514035377) talking to the IDF, ZAKA (Israeli first responders responsible for identifying the dead for proper burial), and other relevant parties: his sources are not aware of this story.
4. [Israeli journalist Chaim Levinson reports](https://twitter.com/chaimlevinson/status/1718907253858640341) checking the story and finding it without factual basis. According to Levinson, Eli Beer's story was based on a comment made by a United Hatzalah volunteer who reported finding a baby with "oven marks", and Beer then expanded on that as an anecdote.

Comment: Chaim Levinson's tweet is here: https://twitter.com/chaimlevinson/status/1718907253858640341

Note: Besides being a journalist, Levinson is also an internet troll.

Comment: Ishai Cohen is here: https://twitter.com/ishaycoen/status/1718888165514035377

Comment: It has been confirmed as true by a first responder that saw with his own eyes. He describes seeing a swollen body of a baby with the heating element still attached. See this article and the linked video at the end of the page (the second part) https://www.jta.org/2023/10/31/israel/an-israeli-first-responder-recalls-tending-to-the-body-of-a-baby-burnt-in-an-oven

Comment: Eli Beer's response is mentioned in the [JTA article](https://www.jta.org/2023/10/31/israel/an-israeli-first-responder-recalls-tending-to-the-body-of-a-baby-burnt-in-an-oven). Not sure if JTA/Sales (the reporter) spoke to him directly.

Comment: @meblum 3 months later when the official list has at most 2 ababies.  Can you reflect on your defintion of confirmed ?